# type definition if a function that when called pollutes the global namespace

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have a plain javascript constructor function that has a static property called `extend`. If we pass a string into this method (`extend`) it will create a new constructor function on the window object.

Here is a implementation of that: https://canjs.com/docs/can.Construct.extend.html

Here is my type definition:

```
declare module "can/construct/" {

    interface ConstructFactory {
        new(): Construct;
    }

    class Construct {
        constructor();
        static extend(name: string): ConstructFactory;
        static extend(name: string, staticProperties: {}): ConstructFactory;
        static extend(name: string, staticProperties: {}, instanceProperties: {}): ConstructFactory;
        static extend(staticProperties: {}, instanceProperties: {}): ConstructFactory;
        static extend(instanceProperties: {}): ConstructFactory;
    }
}
```

My typescript file looks like:

```
import {Construct} from "can/construct/";
Construct.extend('Foo');
let foobar = new Foo();
```

But i get an error:
`TS2304: Cannot find name 'Foo'.`

How can I let typescript know that `Foo` is created in the `extend` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can i letting typescript know that Foo is created in the extend method

You cannot *declare a function that when called pollutes the global namespace*. That feels like a bad idea and so I doubt it will *ever* be supported by TypeScript.

Note: you *can declare a function that will return a constructor variable for you*. But this is not the question you are asking.

Comment: what do you mean with `you can declare a function that will return a constructor variable for you.`

Comment: any thoughts about my last comment?